# Number of combinations w/o repetition that include a certain element

Tags: combinatorics

Given the number of combinations w/o repetition for a set of size n from which you choose k is given by:

n! / k! * (n - k)!

How does one calculate the number of these combinations that include a given element.  That amount should be the same for all elements of the original set.

For example, given the set {A, B, C, D}, there are 6 different ways to pick 2 elements: AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD.  However there are only 3 of these subsets with 'A' in it (AB, AC, AD).  I am stumped on getting to this 3 beyond brute forcing it.

I assume I am missing some formula?

Comment: This question is for [Math at StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

You must choose 1 element, then you can choose any k-1 elements from the remaining n-1. It's the same formula but with n and k replaced with n-1 and k-1 respectively.

```
(n-1)! / (k-1)! * ((n-1) - (k-1))!
```

Comment: This is what I had figured ahead of posting this - however I committed an algebraic brain fade when translating into code so the answer I was getting was not making sense.  Thanks to all that responded!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have 1 element picked for you, you need to pick k-1 element from n-1 remaining, that gives the following formula:

```
(n-1)!/(k-1)!(n-k)!
```

Answer (score 0):

In the {A, B, C, D} example, picking A is already decided, to it reduces to picking the other one out of the three {B, C, D}, which is 3!/1!*(3-1)! = 3.